# No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:<db-name> error on JDBC with Java DB on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jdbc, javadb

Essential parts of the Code:
*(Taken from example from Book: Java How to Program 10th ed, By: Paul Deitel, Harvey Deitel (p. 1063))*:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DisplayAuthors 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby:books";

        try (  
                Connection connection =
                DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "user", "pass"); 
            )
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlException)                                
        {                                                                  
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }                                                   
    } 
}
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Although Java website for [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) says the db is included in JDK, I have
learned after few hours of web searches that openJDK java, the recommended
install on Ubuntu, does not come with the java db.

[The website](http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/derby-javadb/#installing-java-db) that had that helpful information suggested to run:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-javadb-client sun-javadb-core
```

Which produced error and did not install.

So I downloaded jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz, extracted as instructed, and just to be safe(I believe, I could have just set JAVA_HOME, DERBY_HOME to extracted location, and which did "half-worked" upto ij parts[see below]), removed everything from my /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ and replaced with the content of what I downloaded.

And added these in my .bashrc:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/db
export DERBY_HOME
```

Entered in terminal to create database and insert data as instructed in book:

```
$JAVA_HOME/db/bin/ij
connect 'jdbc:derby:books;create=true;user=usr;password=pass';
run 'book-basic-table-create-and-insertions.sql';
exit;
```

It produces a file books with db info+/data inside it.

At ./ there's also a file named derby.log that contains these informations:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Wed Dec 14 19:01:58 EST 2016:
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.11.1.2 - (1629631): instance a816c00e-0158-ffc9-1471-000006d047c8 
on database directory /tmp/deleteme-IuI/books with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6f94fa3e 
Loaded from file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/db/lib/derby.jar
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_111-b14
user.dir=/tmp/deleteme-IuI
os.name=Linux
os.arch=amd64
os.version=4.4.0-53-generic
derby.system.home=null
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
----------------------------------------------------------------
Wed Dec 14 19:04:25 EST 2016: Shutting down Derby engine
----------------------------------------------------------------
Wed Dec 14 19:04:27 EST 2016:
Shutting down instance a816c00e-0158-ffc9-1471-000006d047c8 on database directory /tmp/deleteme-IuI/books with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6f94fa3e 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Compiled and ran:

```
javac DisplayAuthors.java # compiles without error
java DisplayAuthors
```

**Program outputs:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:books
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManagerager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.javaava:247)
at DisplayAuthors.main(DisplayAuthors.java:15)
```

How do I get the program to work?

Comment: */usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/db/lib/derby.jar* (plus other) need to be in you classpath

Comment: You could use Eclipses,  another IDE, or a Maven project in order to more easily get your database driver dependencies

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have tried: `java DisplayAuthors -cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/db/lib/derby.jar` which produced the same error.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'd prefer to use my current setup while learning. I'm not using any IDE, just text editor vim.

Comment: Well, from my experience, most developers prefer an IDE. But that's not really necessary for a Maven or Gradle project anyway

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to pick up an IDE when my projects becomes too big to handle with just text editor.

Comment: Robert, eclipse runs just fine on Linux and is free (as in beer), so I suggest that you try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the load driver section of code

e.g.

```
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
...
try {
    Class.forName(driver); 
} catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
  ...
}
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/getstart/rwwdactivity3.html for an example

**Edit**

As a proof I have done the following

1. create simple java project in Eclipse
2. add derby.jar, derbynet.jar & derbyclient.jat to classpath

My Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver); 
    } catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true;user=user;password=pass";

    try (  
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "user", "pass"); 
        )
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlException)                                
    {                                                                  
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }        

}
```

This runs without Exceptions

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, even longer error message with your catch stack trace:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException...
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:books

Comment: My code does not mention `jdbc:derby:books`.  Are you calling my code **before** your code?  Did you look at the link I gave you?  Are you using an embedded db ?

Comment: yes, I'm calling your code before mine. I am very new to database, I'm not sure what I'm using, just following the book (although it should be embedded if it is - as opposed to server(?)), the code on the post and step as I mentioned on it is all I have regarding these.

Comment: have a look at `ij.sh` and see what they are doing.  I read the link you provided in your question and I am confused as to what driver they are using and whether they are using embedded or server

Comment: I am not very familiar with bash scripting, not too sure what they are doing. No changes were made to the file. I don't want to post it here as it may be copyrighted, but can be found after extracting: "jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz" and in it db/bin/ij. Download link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: well for a start they do `# set local classpath, don't overwrite the user's
LOCALCLASSPATH=$DERBY_LIB/derby.jar:$DERBY_LIB/derbynet.jar:$DERBY_LIB/derbytools.jar:$DERBY_LIB/derbyclient.jar`  so maybe add these to your classpath

Comment: I have tried in terminal `LOCALCLASSPATH=$DERBY_LIB/derby.jar:$DERBY_LIB/derbynet.jar:‌​$DERBY_LIB/derbytool‌​s.jar:$DERBY_LIB/der‌​byclient.jar`

ran, same error.

Tried again `java DisplayAuthors -cp $DERBY_LIB/derby.jar:$DERBY_LIB/derbynet.jar:‌​$DERBY_LIB/derbytool‌​s.jar:$DERBY_LIB/der‌​byclient.jar`

Same error.

Comment: I see from your original question that you set and exported `DERBY_HOME` but I do not think you have set `DERBY_LIB`

Comment: BTW the second way that you run your program is probably correct

Comment: I did:
`DERBY_LIB=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/db/lib/`

And re-ran in the same terminal with:
`java DisplayAuthors -cp $DERBY_LIB/derby.jar:$DERBY_LIB/derbynet.jar:‌​$DERBY_LIB/de‌​rbytool‌​s.jar:$DERB‌​Y_LIB/der‌​byclient.‌​jar`

I have confirmed that the jar files are in the DERBY_LIB directory. Same error unfortunately.

Comment: try `export DERBY_LIB=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/db/lib/`

Comment: please post the full stack trace

Comment: They are exactly the same as noted by the end of my question. If there is any way to print more detailed stack trace, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Also see and follow this link https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html

Comment: The code is same. As I have mentioned adding the bits you suggested on your post (before mine), outputs extra java.lang.ClassNotFoundException if stack trace is outputted. 

For The link, I'm not sure what exactly should I look at. Not sure what localhost is used for. I believe I have the database url fine as I just copied it from the book.

I should note that I do very much appreciate you taking time to suggest fixes.

Comment: Loading driver classes should not be necessary with JDBC 4+ compliant drivers.

Comment: Thanks @ScaryWombat !, everything works fine, the issue was with classpath.

@MarkRotteveel Yes, without the explicit driver class usage, my program seems to work fine.

The exact command that made the program work:
`java -cp .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/db/lib/* DisplayAuthors`